# How to order posts list using wp_query?

Tags: wordpress

I want to order my list with wp_query. I have posts with meta_key 'featured_post' and three values for that key for different posts it is: '1', '2', and thrird key not exist.

I am using now this wp_query structure:

```
global $paged, $wp_query, $wp;
$args = wp_parse_args($wp->matched_query);
if ( !empty ( $args['paged'] ) && 0 == $paged ) {
    $wp_query->set('paged', $args['paged']);
    $paged = $args['paged'];
}
$temp = $wp_query;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        'featured_clause_first' => array(
            'key' => 'featured_post',
            'value' => '1',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        'featured_clause_second' => array(
            'key' => 'featured_post',
            'value' => '2',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        'featured_clause_third' => array(
            'key' => 'featured_post',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            'value' => '1'
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => array( 
        'featured_clause_first' => 'DESC',
        'featured_clause_second' => 'DESC',
        'featured_clause_third' => 'DESC'
    ),

);
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
    get_template_part( 'templates/single');
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
wp_reset_query();
```

But I am got wrong order. Finally I need to see posts with value '1' at the top and other posts with values '2' and not exist key after.

Note: I can't use "'meta_key' => 'featured_post'," because in this way posts without existing meta_key not displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I was edited save metabox functions for delete metakey if featured not checked. So that I have only two values: 1 & key not exist. After that I got needed order with this meta args:

```
$sort_meta_query = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    'featured_clause' => array(
        'key' => 'featured_post',
        'value' => '1',
        'compare' => '='
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'featured_post',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        'value' => '1'
    )
);
$sort = array(
    'orderby' => array(
        'featured_clause' => 'DESC',
        'date' => 'DESC'
    )
);
```